# Which way is faster to load page in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Which way is faster to load webpages in uiwebivew

using

> Loading NSData into a UIWebView

OR

> using Load Request URL?

Comment: please check [this](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/uiwebview-tutorial.html) link

Answer (score 1):

Network requests take time.  There's no point in trying to optimize a few milliseconds off this type of code.  Write the code that is most readable / maintainable and it will serve you better.

You could put the webpage, scripts, css, and images in your app bundle; get a URL that points to it (file://...) and use that.  Within your webpage, you can use AJAX to pull in some dynamic data, etc.

That'd be a better path to optimize; but it all depends on your situation.

If you have the option of using `loadRequest`, I'd recommend it.  Let the OS take the work off your hands.

edit:
PS: UIWebView tends to take it's time about displaying data; even when no network is involved.
I often set the webview's alpha to 0 in IB or viewDidLoad; then fade it in when the content is ready.

Inside your `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method, add this:

```
if (0.0f == webview.alpha) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                     animations:^{
                         webview.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Their is really isn't any "technical" way to load Webview faster, But I would recommend you use:

> Load Request URL

Load Request URL Code:

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Request Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

Comment: Hi iProgrammed, is there any way to load faster (one or two seconds also ok :) in Load Request URL method?

Comment: I don't any but the Network Speed of your Device should help make the URL load a couple more seconds faster.